# Парсинг страниц с Frame Android Studio

Tags: java, android, парсер

Мне необходимо парсить страницы сайта с фреймами. Разметка содержит в себе несколько `frame`, в них нужные мне данные. `Jsoup` вытаскивает страницу где содержимое фреймов пустое.

Я так понимаю мне необходимо дождаться полной загрузки всех элементов страницы (также и в хроме, в "просмотре кода страницы" фреймы пусты, но когда ищешь через "посмотреть код" то весь код из фреймов присутствует). Подскажите как парсить сайты такого рода в Java Android?

Делал подобное на C# но там для этого использовал `WebBrowser` и обрабатывал событие по завершении загрузки страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что речь идёт об `iframe`.

Задачу можно попробовать решить по аналогии с C#. В Android SDK, есть аналог `WebBrowser`, который называется `WebView`. Либо парсить адрес фрейма и по нему грузить данные.

Как-то так...

Comment: А если нет адреса фрейма? На сайте вот такой блок `<div class="frame frame-base frame_type_common frame_theme_white" style=""><div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-frame no_padding">` и в нем фрейм выводится, не могу понять как такое достается [ссылка](https://alfabank.ru/currency/)  там где таблица с курсами.

Comment: Судя по коду фрейм это обычный див и заполняется он скриптом. Правда (это уже моё ИМХО) парсить таблицу с курсами валют через HTML это устаревший подход. Есть же бесплатные API для этого (гугл в помощь).

Comment: Спасибо за совет, этот сайт привел для примера, не всегда есть возможность использовать API, бывает нужны другие данные. С помощью WebView можно получить этот код полностью также, как его получает пользователь после погрузки страницы? (просто пока не могу найти ничего подходящего...)

Comment: Я же писал в ответе...